# How do I pass variables to scss processor?

Tags: python, vue.js, sass, tornado

My current set up is 
Front-end:
VueJS

Backend
Python, Tornado

Vue is used using the cdn for indivudual static templates. 
Tornado serves the templates.
I'm using the python scss library to compile the scss, that part of pretty straight forward.

```
sass.compile(dirname=(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'static/scss'), os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'static/css')), output_style='compressed')
```

I have two config.py files that hold configurations with two different color schemes among other things, I would like to use pass the color vars in those files to the scss file but don't know if there's a way/possible.

I can pass global variables to the templates using tornado but that's not what I need because the scss file has to get compiled using those colors before that happens.
I've done tons of research before this but can't find exactly what I need so maybe someone has done this before.

Comment: if curious to see more of the lib used: https://sass.github.io/libsass-python/  I've looked at this a lot so not asking to do my homework, just hoping someone has encountered this issue as I'm a newish dev in Python

Comment: Why are you storing colour schemes in Python files?

Comment: It's an unusual project, have to reuse the same template with different content and styles. The backend is python so I just need to figure out to distribute that info to the right compiles.

Comment: Can't you group the styles by a class on the body? And then all you have to do is set a class on the body for a given style and browsers will override the defaults. For example, `.green-body {background: green;} .green-body a {color: yellow;}`. So if you set the class `green-body` on the body, it will get a green background and all the links will get a yellow colour.

Comment: This template would potentially be used by many users so that would be too many cases to hard code. Trying to move all specific info out of the template into a config file. Thank you for sharing your idea tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah-ha! You can pass [custom functions](https://sass.github.io/libsass-python/sass.html#custom-functions) to the compiler to communicate with the file.

https://sass.github.io/libsass-python/sass.html#custom-functions